# Old lego set 1950s or 60s? TABAC and/or BAKEREI (from Europe)

Tags: set-identification, vintage

My dad had a lego set (or 2 sets) in the late 50s or early 60s that his dad picked up in Europe (this was before they were sold in the states).  It had 2 thick green rectangular tiles for bottoms (or one in each set) and made 2 buildings - TABAC and  BAKEREI if he remembers the 1x6 blocks that had names on them correctly.  Can anyone identify this set (or pair of sets)?  Thanks so much

Answer (score 5):

The set(s) in question are likely two versions of set [1210 Small Store](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=1210-2), released in 1955, or [210 Small Store](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=210-2), sold in 1958. They were available in a number of languages and with a variety of store names. "Tabak" means Tobacco in both Dutch and German. The Dutch word for bakery, however, is "bakkerij", while in German it is "Bäckerei". "Bakerei" is only used in Basque. Most likely, your father had two copies of the German versions of the sets.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks so much.  Based on what he told me about them, I bet that's exactly it.